# Android new task problem

Tags: android

I have two activities in my application.one of the activity started by service class ,so i have set the flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** and start the activity.

in that activity i hide the status bar by using the following code .

> getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

The problem is some time the activity not hiding the statusbar.After doing several testing i found that the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** is creating problem.

how to solve this?

Comment: are you calling it before `setContentView` ?

Comment: it is interesting to know "how did you discover that this is being caused by FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK"

Answer (score 2):

What if you do that directly in the XML:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```